# Drawing lines on cartesian coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do I express this into LaTeX code? I'm new, and I have no idea how to this (I think it requires `pgfplots`/`tikz`). Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). What have you tried so far? Please always provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and loading all necessary packages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar to what you show drawn with `pgfplots` to start with:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
     \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=both,
        grid,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        xmin=-5, 
        xmax=5,
        xtick = {-5,...,5},
        ytick = {-5,...,5},
        ]       
        
        \draw[stealth-stealth,very thick] (axis cs:-4,-4) -- (axis cs:3,4) node[below right] at (axis cs:0,0) {A};
        \draw[stealth-stealth,very thick] (axis cs:-2,-3) -- (axis cs:-2,4) node[left] at (axis cs:-2,1) {B};
    
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I change the "very thick" on the line?

Comment: Yes, why not. You can either just delete it, leave it to just `thick` or custom the line thickness with `line width=<value>pt`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a bit improved version of [Roland's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619489/95441).

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat` level or higher to place TikZ coordinates by default
    % in axis coordinates. That means TikZ coordinates don't have to be given
    % the coordinate system `axis cs:` explicitly.
    % It is best practice to use the actual version, i.e. here it would be 1.18.
    % That ensures that you use the most recent features.
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % create a style for the lines that can later be used
    my line style/.style={
        >=stealth,
        <->,
        very thick,
    }
]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=both,
        grid,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=5,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=1,
    ]

        \draw [my line style] (-4,-4) -- ( 3,4)
            % to place a node long the path either give everything explicitly ...
            node [below right,red] at (0,0) {A};
        \draw [my line style] (-2,-3) -- (-2,4)
            % ... or a bit simplified.
            node [auto,pos=0.6] {B};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]